# Why does my Canon PIXMA iX6520 use so much black ink?

Tags: printing, ink

Why does my Canon PIXMA iX6520 use so much black ink?  I printed about 300 pages of minimal content (simple line drawings with titles), and the black ink is almost completely depleted.

Comment: Corrected the model number. This is the best guess based on the closest match Google was able to provide; feel free to revert or edit the question again if it is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a new printer?

Most cheap new printers come with "starter" print cartridges, which contain less ink than the standard replacement cartridges that you can buy.

The reason for that is that ink is expensive. By including less ink, they can sell the printer for a lower price. That makes the printer more attractive.

Some manufacturers mention that on their website or brochures and some don't.

I am looking into buying a Brother colour laser printer. Their currently cheapest model, the HL3150CDN, ships with colour cartridges that last 1000 pages. The standard cartridges last 1400 pages.

A higher end model, the HLL8250CDN, which is 3 times as expensive, ships with standard cartridges, lasting 1500 pages.

Answer (score 2):

#### Initial cartridges generally have lower yields than normal, and ink is often wasted on maintaining the printer especially if you don't print often.

- As others have noted, if this is a new printer, it likely came with initial or starter cartridges which have lower yields than normal. In addition, the printer needs to use some of the ink in the first set of cartridges to prime the ink system. All this means that you should expect lower than normal page yields on the first set of cartridges than on cartridges you buy and install after you use up the initial set.
- If you don't print often (at least once a week or so), inkjet printers tend to waste significant amounts of ink on maintaining themselves to prevent the printhead from drying up. These maintenance operations include printhead cleaning and ensuring that the printhead is primed at all times (as running the printhead dry can cause it to fail). Some are better than others in this regard; HP printers, especially those which use cartridges with combined printhead and ink, tend to waste the least ink on maintenance.

#### There are many options available to you that can reduce cost per page.

- If you do not need color or high-quality graphics output (beyond line graphics), a monochrome laser printer is likely to provide far lower cost per page. I'd recommend the [Brother HL-L2340DW](http://www.brother-usa.com/Printer/ModelDetail/1/HLL2340DW/overview) for its combination of affordable supplies and high print speeds, but be sure to shop around to make sure you buy the best printer for your needs.
- If you do print a lot and need the graphical image quality of an inkjet printer, you have several options:

  - You can use third-party (aftermarket, non-OEM) cartridges. I personally don't recommend this because you will generally get lower quality, reliability, and print permanence than original supplies, especially if the cartridges are not from a reputable brand. A good choice for third-party supplies would be [LD Products](http://www.ldproducts.com/).
  - You can invest in a more expensive office printer, such as an [Epson WorkForce](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Landing/workforce-office-printers-for-business.do?ref=van_workforce) or [HP OfficeJet Pro](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/printers/officejet-pro-printers.html) printer. These tend to accept large, high-yield cartridges for significantly lower cost per page, and will pay for themselves over a few thousand pages of printing. A more advanced office printer will also print faster, which can save valuable time if you're regularly doing large print jobs. (I own an HP Officejet Pro 8630; print speeds are very good and cost per page is very low with the XL cartridges.)
  - If you have high print volume (200+ pages a month) and print permanence is not a concern (you do not need prints to last more than a few years or so before they noticeably fade), you can consider the [Epson EcoTank series](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Landing/ecotank-super-tank-printers.do), which features an integrated [continuous ink supply system (CISS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_ink_system) for extremely low cost per page. Despite the very high initial cost, these will very easily pay for themselves with enough print volume. However, the external ink tanks mean you'll need to be careful when refilling ink or moving the printer to another location.
  - Many newer HP printers offer a "printing as a service" option called [HP Instant Ink](https://instantink.hpconnected.com/us/en/r). This service works like a mobile phone plan: instead of buying cartridges, you pay a monthly fee for the right to print a specific number of pages each month. You'll be charged the same price each month regardless of the amount of ink actually used, so photo printing or other tasks that use large amounts of ink do not incur an additional cost. Overages are subject to a (reasonable) extra charge while unused pages can roll over to the next month. The printer automatically orders replacement cartridges as needed, so you will never need to worry about keeping sufficient ink on hand.

Answer (score 0):

Starter cartridges likely provide half the ink of full cartridges if you are still on your first cartridge.

More importantly, if you only use the machine occassionally, it is going to [waste A LOT of ink on self cleaning](http://atomicshrimp.com/post/2008/04/06/The-Dirty-Little-Secret-Of-Inkjet-Printers).